# How to re-use groovy script for reading csv files

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have number of test cases in my project. I am using soap ui open source.

To read the csv files i am using the below code.

DataSource

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
//Define Path
def csvFilePath = "D:\\URL.csv"
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath))
//Header
firstline = context.fileReader.readLine()
//Actual Test Data
firstline = context.fileReader.readLine()
//Split data with comma
String[] data = firstline.split(",")
log.info data[0]
log.info data[1]
//Assign each comma separated value to the Property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("username", data[0])
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("userrole", data[1])
```

DataLoop: To Loop Back

```
nextline = context.fileReader.readLine()
if(nextline!=null)
{
String[] data = nextline.split(",")
log.info data[0]
log.info data[1]
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("username", data[0])
context.testCase.setPropertyValue("userrole", data[1])
//context.testCase.setPropertyValue("roledescription", data[2])
//Navigate to AddUser Step to run again with the next row
testRunner.gotoStepByName("AddUsers")
}
```

To use these in each test cases, i have to clone on each test case.. I have created Reading first Line as TestCase1 and the next part as TestCase2. I am calling these scripts from RunTestCase option.

But unfortunately, I am getting error cannot invoke method readline on null object.

So I added the reference in the Dataloop part. But it creates infinite loop.. Is there any way to reuse?

Comment: Not sure if the above script helps even if you clone? Check this https://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/groovy-datasource-teststep-dataloop-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui/

Comment: Here is the better way to deal with csv in groovy - https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv

Comment: The code which is working fine on using in same test case. But keep it away and reusing concept is not working..

Comment: How is your test case structure? What parameters you are using / passing to `Run test case`? a screen shot would help.

Comment: What you are doing is not really the standard way. Because, if the project is run, then it would be in trouble again as `Test case 1, 2` are not really the test cases.

Comment: I don't real think that k

Comment: Sorry, did not get your comment. If your objective is to create a library and re-use, see http://rupertanderson.com/blog/1-how-to-develop-add-and-use-a-custom-groovy-library-in-soapui/#comment-23

Comment: I am able to run it and working as a in Test case.. I will shelve Test Case1 and Test case2 and disable it. So that it will not be a part of run.. But it will supply the info wherever needed.. But problem is how to reuse the filereader object..

Comment: I achieved through apache poi..

Answer (score -1):

Copy all your Groovy code in an external file and name it as AddUser.groovy
Then add new groovy script in your testcase and just put
**evaluate(new File('path/to/AddUser.groovy'));**
It will help you to reuse your groovy script in different testcases